# OPENCV- TypeError: integer argument expected, got float

Tags: python, error-handling, opencv

Guys I am trying to follow this quick tutorial.
Also I am trying to learn every code that we type.
But I got an error. I am trying to learn every code so can you please tell me why I am getting this error? And how to solve this error?

I get the error in function of **def draw_lines(img, lines, color=[255, 0, 0], thickness=3):**

**The Error I get:**

> File "C:\Users\alpgu\Desktop\opencv\yolboyama.py", line 112, in
>
> poly_left = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(
>
> File "<**array_function** internals>", line 5, in polyfit
>
> File
> "C:\Users\alpgu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\polynomial.py",
> line 599, in polyfit
> raise TypeError("expected non-empty vector for x")
>
> TypeError: expected non-empty vector for x

I think problem is about the line of::

```
poly_left = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(
        left_line_y,
        left_line_x,
        deg=1
    ))
```

Why it is happening?

Note==>
When I change my max x and min y codes(you said it should be int so I tried to change my code. I also tried to do int but it gives another error. So I couldnt understand what should I do know?)::

```
min_y = int(yol_resmi.shape * (3 / 5)) # <-- Just below the horizon
    max_y = int(yol_resmi.shape)
```

It gives the error of

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Is The problem about my max_x - min_y values or is the problem about my polly_left value?

All of my code:

```
from os.path import sep
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('photos' + sep + 'roads.mp4')

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, yol_resmi = cap.read()
    
    # Define a blank matrix that matches the image height/width.
    def region_of_interest(img, vertices):
        mask = np.zeros_like(img)
        
        channel_count = yol_resmi.shape[2]
        
        match_mask_color = (255,) * channel_count
        
        cv2.fillPoly(mask, vertices, match_mask_color)
        
        masked_image = cv2.bitwise_and(img, mask)
        return masked_image
    
    height, width, channel = yol_resmi.shape 
    
    region_of_interest_vertices = [
        (0, height),
        (width / 2, height / 2),
        (width, height),
    ]
    
    def draw_lines(img, lines, color=[255, 0, 0], thickness=3):
        line_img = np.zeros(
            (
                img.shape[0],
                img.shape[1],
                3
            ),
            dtype=np.uint8
        )
        img = np.copy(img)
        if lines is None:
            return
        for line in lines:
            for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line:
                cv2.line(line_img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), color, thickness)
        img = cv2.addWeighted(img, 0.8, line_img, 1.0, 0.0)
        return img
    
    #COLOR_BGR2GRAY ekle
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(yol_resmi, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    cannyed_image = cv2.Canny(gray_image, 200, 300)
    cropped_image = region_of_interest(
        cannyed_image,
        np.array(
            [region_of_interest_vertices],
            np.int32
        ),
    )
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(
        cropped_image,
        rho=6,
        theta=np.pi / 60,
        threshold=160,
        lines=np.array([]),
        minLineLength=40,
        maxLineGap=25
    )
    print(lines)
    
    line_image = draw_lines(yol_resmi, lines)
    
    left_line_x = []
    left_line_y = []
    right_line_x = []
    right_line_y = []
    
    for line in lines:
        for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line:
            slope = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1) # <-- Calculating the slope.
            if math.fabs(slope) < 0.5: # <-- Only consider extreme slope
                continue
            if slope <= 0: # <-- If the slope is negative, left group.
                left_line_x.extend([x1, x2])
                left_line_y.extend([y1, y2])
            else: # <-- Otherwise, right group.
                right_line_x.extend([x1, x2])
                right_line_y.extend([y1, y2])
    min_y = yol_resmi.shape[0] * (3 / 5) # <-- Just below the horizon
    max_y = yol_resmi.shape[0] # <-- The bottom of the image
    poly_left = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(
        left_line_y,
        left_line_x,
        deg=1
    ))
    left_x_start = int(poly_left(max_y))
    left_x_end = int(poly_left(min_y))
    poly_right = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(
        right_line_y,
        right_line_x,
        deg=1
    ))
    right_x_start = int(poly_right(max_y))
    right_x_end = int(poly_right(min_y))
    line_image = draw_lines(
        yol_resmi,
        [[
            [left_x_start, max_y, left_x_end, min_y],
            [right_x_start, max_y, right_x_end, min_y],
        ]],
        thickness=5,
    )
    
    # Convert to grayscale here.
    #gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(cropped_image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    
    # Call Canny Edge Detection here.
    #cannyed_image = cv2.Canny(gray_image, 100, 200)
    
    #cv2.imshow('yol resmi', yol_resmi)
    cv2.imshow('edge detection', cropped_image)
    cv2.imshow('line detection', line_image)
    #cv2.imshow('Edge Detection', cannyed_image)
    
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: I think it is because of this line ```min_y = yol_resmi.shape[0] * (3 / 5) # <-- Just below the horizon``` so ```min_y``` is float but should be int

Comment: I will try it and write you the conclusion

Comment: How can I solve this?

Comment: @crackanddie sir are you there?

Comment: I was asleep :) I'll try to look for the error again a little later

Comment: okey let me explain, I am editing my question

Comment: Okey I have editted my question. can you look again?

Comment: Sir any further news?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is all that I could do:

```py
from os.path import sep
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math
import warnings

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('photos' + sep + 'roads.mp4')

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, yol_resmi = cap.read()

    # Define a blank matrix that matches the image height/width.
    def region_of_interest(img, vertices):
        mask = np.zeros_like(img)

        channel_count = yol_resmi.shape[2]

        match_mask_color = (255,) * channel_count

        cv2.fillPoly(mask, vertices, match_mask_color)

        masked_image = cv2.bitwise_and(img, mask)
        return masked_image


    height, width, channel = yol_resmi.shape

    region_of_interest_vertices = [
        (0, height),
        (width / 2, height / 2),
        (width, height),
    ]


    def draw_lines(img, lines, color=[255, 0, 0], thickness=3):
        line_img = np.zeros(
            (
                img.shape[0],
                img.shape[1],
                3
            ),
            dtype=np.uint8
        )
        img = np.copy(img)
        if lines is None:
            return
        for line in lines:
            for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line:
                print(type(x1), type(x2), type(y1), type(y2))
                cv2.line(line_img, (x1, y1), (x2, int(y2)), color, thickness)
        img = cv2.addWeighted(img, 0.8, line_img, 1.0, 0.0)
        return img


    # COLOR_BGR2GRAY ekle
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(yol_resmi, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    cannyed_image = cv2.Canny(gray_image, 200, 300)
    cropped_image = region_of_interest(
        cannyed_image,
        np.array(
            [region_of_interest_vertices],
            np.int32
        ),
    )
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(
        cropped_image,
        rho=6,
        theta=np.pi / 60,
        threshold=160,
        lines=np.array([]),
        minLineLength=40,
        maxLineGap=25
    )
    print(lines)
    print(len(lines))

    line_image = draw_lines(yol_resmi, lines)

    left_line_x = [0, 0]
    left_line_y = [0, 0]
    right_line_x = [0, 0]
    right_line_y = [0, 0]

    for line in lines:
        for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line:
            slope = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)  # <-- Calculating the slope.
            if math.fabs(slope) < 0.5:  # <-- Only consider extreme slope
                continue
            if slope <= 0:  # <-- If the slope is negative, left group.
                left_line_x = [x1, x2]
                left_line_y = [y1, y2]
            else:  # <-- Otherwise, right group.
                right_line_x = [x1, x2]
                right_line_y = [y1, y2]
    min_y = yol_resmi.shape[0] * (3 / 5)  # <-- Just below the horizon
    max_y = yol_resmi.shape[0]  # <-- The bottom of the image
    try:
        poly_left = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(
            left_line_y,
            left_line_x,
            deg=1
        ))
        left_x_start = int(poly_left(max_y))
        left_x_end = int(poly_left(min_y))
        poly_right = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(
            right_line_y,
            right_line_x,
            deg=1
        ))
        right_x_start = int(poly_right(max_y))
        right_x_end = int(poly_right(min_y))
    except np.linalg.LinAlgError as e:
        warnings.warn("There is no lines in chosen region")
        cv2.imshow('line detection', yol_resmi)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
        continue
    line_image = draw_lines(
        yol_resmi,
        [[
            [left_x_start, max_y, left_x_end, min_y],
            [right_x_start, max_y, right_x_end, min_y],
        ]],
        thickness=5,
    )

    # Convert to grayscale here.
    # gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(cropped_image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

    # Call Canny Edge Detection here.
    # cannyed_image = cv2.Canny(gray_image, 100, 200)

    # cv2.imshow('yol resmi', yol_resmi)
    cv2.imshow('edge detection', cropped_image)
    cv2.imshow('line detection', line_image)
    # cv2.imshow('Edge Detection', cannyed_image)

    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: thanks sir, I am not at in a available time to test it. I will try it soon. I will write here

Comment: because I added a try except part into your code. I did it because in some cases variables ```left_line_y, left_line_x, right_line_y, right_line_x``` are equal to 0. Sorry but I don't know what does your code should do so as I understood sometimes it can't find any lines in a frame. So you just should think over your code and write somewhere exception handler

Comment: sir can I send the link of an video, it is about 1 mins that explains my question and what my code does

Comment: yes, please. But I hope you are not in a hurry, if you still need my help, I can only do it in about a day, because I have some ploblems here

Comment: Okey okey, no problem thank you again for your responses

Comment: Sir ıf my english is bad sorry for that. My video link is here : https://vimeo.com/512603582

Comment: Sir any further news?

Comment: yes, I watched your video, thought a little and understood. When you set your own ```region_of_interest_vertices``` program may not find any lines in this region that's why window with image doesn't opens. Not exactly that of course. It won't open till there are error in the code and errors occur because it can't find lines. So I can say that your first code was normal, but if any error occures your program will stop. In my solution - if any error occures program will wait untill there won't be errors. I hope you understood. So now I really don't know how can I help you

Comment: but problem is in my previous code detects some lines in also other regions.

Comment: Is it can be about exception?Maybe I should change np.linalg.LinAlgError this?

Comment: no, it means that errors are already somewhere in the image processing. Unfortunately, we are breaking community guidelines, so I ask you to open a new question on this topic. But I most likely will not be able to help you in this matter ```but problem is in my previous code detects some lines in also other regions.```

Comment: yes I got it now but is there any way to keep opening the imshow windows while it doesnt detect lines

Comment: yes sir, Thanks for every answer. You helped me so much.

Comment: Sir, I have opened a new question. If you are able to answer or if you want to answer, ı will be so happy :) link ==>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66292414/opencv-curve-the-tope-of-liine-to-detected-object